# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I run a Objective-c project and suddenly it stopped getting build.It only show the following error.Problem is I could not where that error comes from.I m new to IOS

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNTCE.jpg]

Comment: share some more detail to get exact error.

Comment: Click the log File Link  it shows the Error.Thank you.problem is it docent show where error comes from.It came suddenly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to clean build your project.

Try to clean build your project(**alt+product+clean build project**) and run your project again.

Answer (score 0):

The error could happen when Xcode is building and you modify or implement some part of the code where Xcode is trying to build.

Try Clean Build Folder (**Shift + Cmd + K**) wait until the process complete and Build (**Cmd + B**) or Run (Cmd + R) again.